# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (10,1) into shape (10)

Tags: python, numpy

I'm having issues with something I though would be fairly simple.  I'm trying to populate a zeros matrix with data from a for loop, but I keep getting the error: "ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (10,1) into shape (10)"

My code is below:

```
import numpy as np
import random

def hire(n = 10, nRuns = 2):

    data = np.array(np.zeros((n,nRuns)))
    i = 0

    while i < nRuns:
        cand = [[w] for w in range(1,n+1)] 
        random.shuffle(cand) 

        look = np.zeros((n,1))
        track = np.zeros((n,1))

        for M in range(0,n-1):
            look[M] = cand[M]
            lookbest = max(look)
            left = cand[M:]

            for q in range(0, n-M-1):
                if left[q] > lookbest:
                    track[M] = left[i]
                    break
                else:
                    pass

        data[:,i] = track #the error occurs right here

        i = i + 1
```

Why is data[n,nRuns].shape = (10,) instead of (10,1)?  And how can I make this work?

Comment: You are doing 'single element indexing': https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/user/basics.indexing.html#single-element-indexing.  Also make sure you understand 'broadcasting':  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html.

Comment: A slice of a 2D array (i.e. row or column, i.e. `data[:,i]`), is a 1D array. You are trying to set a 2D array into a 1D array. Size matches but dimension doesn't. Simple solution: use `data[:,i] = track.flatten()` instead of `data[:,i] = track`

Answer (score 1):

`data[:,i]` creates a rank 1 slice of the data array, e.g. that's why its shape is (10,) rather than (10,1). The extra dimension is length 1, it's extraneous. You should allocate track to also be rank 1:

```
track = np.zeros(n)
```

You could reshape `data[:,i]` to give it that extra dimension, but that's unnecessary; you're only using the first dimension of `track` and `look`, so just make them 1-D instead of 2-D

(that style of having to declare two dimensions for an array is very Matlab-like; I always hated that the Matlab default was to create a 2D array, but in numpy the default is 1D, much simpler and more intuitive)